# How can I fix "CL.exe" exited with code 2

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, visual-studio-2019, cl.exe

I have been following learnopengl.com and I was on the Transformations part of the website and it keeps saying

> CL.exe" exited with code 2

This is making impossible to test anything because it will not build.

I have tried many things, I have tried copying all the code from the tutorial and then tried running it but it still was giving the same error. I Have tried restarting visual studio in case it was an intellisense error but still no success.

It says the code that's causing the issue is part of Microsoft.CppCommon.targets on line 429 and it doesn't give much more info than that
but here's the line that's giving the error

```
<CL Condition="'%(ClCompile.PrecompiledHeader)' != 'Create' and '%(ClCompile.ExcludedFromBuild)'!='true' and '%(ClCompile.CompilerIteration)' == '' and @(ClCompile) != ''"
```

and here is some of the code that is underneath it

```
BuildingInIDE                      ="$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)"
Sources                            ="@(ClCompile)"
```

but it's not telling me what's causing the error so I don't know what the problem is.

it should just compile and run completely fine but it keeps giving the same error over and over again.

Comment: Seems like a toolchain misconfiguration/malinstallation

Answer (score 3):

I have observed clear case of this. It was due to function with bool return type but function lacked return statement.

Example:

```
bool DontForgetToReturnBool()
{
    // Everything except return statement
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

These errors can be frustrating because the compiler is supposed to inform us of the error, however, it's usually something simple, so just comment out recent code changes and re-compile until you find it.

Comment: It seems unlikely that this scenario is the cause of the described problem.

Comment: it's not giving me any more info than that CL.exe exited with code 2. which makes no sense to me. so I'm not sure what's wrong but I think it might be a bug with visual studio.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug with Microsoft compiler. Once I added the return statement, the problem was resolved.As I say, this is one clear and definite example that I have observed, there may be other examples. (Microsoft may be investing less in C++ due to the popularity of clang etc.)

Comment: so what changes do I need to make to my code for it to work here's the link pastebin.com/EUbGF5fd

Comment: This was the exact problem I had, why couldn't it just say I didn't have a return statement lol